# Limit amount of results from one table, but allow infinite from another

Tags: mysql

I've got this query:

```
SELECT *, m.id AS mooringid
                    FROM mooring m JOIN customer c ON m.assignedTo = c.id
                    WHERE m.Number = :var OR (CONCAT(c.TitleName,' ',c.Surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :var, '%')) OR m.MooringArea = :var
                    ORDER BY c.Surname limit 0,250
```

That is supposed to get elements assigned to a customer from another table, the only way I saw that I could do this is by "infusing" the customer details with the element, returning the elements but I want to limit the amount of customers returned but allow infinite elements, however, this limits the elements rather than the customer and that just doesn't work in my situation.

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: If the intent is to limit the table that is joined, you'd have to use a subquery as the joined table I believe. This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP (other than the variables in the query), so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle the issue is to do a subquery on customers and extract the number you need.  Something like:

```
from (select c.*
      from customers c
      limit 100
     ) c
```

But, in your case, you have a lot of secondary filtering going on (with the join conditions and the where).  Instead, add a customer counter to each row and use that for selecting a certain number of customers:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT *, m.id AS mooringid,
             @rn := if(@cid = c.id, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @cid = c.id
      FROM mooring m JOIN
           customer c
           ON m.assignedTo = c.id cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @cid := -1) const
      WHERE m.Number = :var OR
            (CONCAT(c.TitleName,' ',c.Surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :var, '%')) OR
            m.MooringArea = :var
      ORDER BY c.Surname
     ) t
order by c.SurName
where rn <= 10;
```